# How can I determine std::isgraph in any language for a UTF-8 string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, locale

I'm researching string encodings and locales. Oh joy!

Essentially I want to check that every character in a UTF-8 string is graphical, like `isgraph` but for all Unicode characters.

Here's what I've established so far, but I don't know how to put it together.

- I can extract the characters from a UTF-8 string with [std::codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt).
- I can then use [std::isgraph(charT, const locale&)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isgraph)

I believe converting UTF-8 to UTF-32 will be the most general solution and it will look like this:

```
template<class Facet>

struct deletable_facet : Facet
{
    template<class ...Args>
    deletable_facet (Args&& ...args) : Facet (std::forward<Args> (args)...) {}
};

std::wstring_convert<deletable_facet<std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>, char32_t> conv32;

std::u32string str32 = conv32.from_bytes (data)
```

But the example for `isgraph` doesn't fill me with confidence:

```
std::locale loc2 ("en_US.UTF-8");
std::isgraph (c, loc2)
```

The documentation says the string argument is "OS-specific". Also the example suggests that I need to specify a *language* as well as an encoding.

My strings may be English, French, Japanese, whatever.

How can I determine that a character in a UTF-8 string is graphical in *any* language?

Comment: I'm not sure that whether a character is graphical is affected by language

Comment: C++ predates Unicode, and it doesn't require Unicode (nor the locales requires Unicode). Read the comment "OS-specific" in such way. Note: the number of glyphs depends on language (because of ligatures, see e.g. many Indic languages)